# Runtime error: cannot find the an activity to launch the intent. I am trying to view and retrieve my pdf documents stored on FirebaseStorage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

This is my java code, I receive an error saying that no activity was found to open the intent.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //getting the upload
            Upload upload = uploadList.get(i);

            //Opening the upload file in browser using the upload url
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(upload.getUrl()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Can someone help please? below is the code on getting the url and storing in firebaseDatabase, seems there is a problem with that too..

```
Upload upload = new Upload(editTextFilename.getText().toString(), taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                    mDatabaseReference.child(mDatabaseReference.push().getKey()).setValue(upload);
```

Comment: [Upload files with Cloud storage on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Honestly speaking there are a lot of steps to do, but Follow the above link guide first to get your first step done by creating a database to store your data first so that you can proceed to next step by coding out the functions needed that you state above.

I highly suggest you to fully read and understand the datatypes to select for what you want to store in your database example like String, Int, Double etc. Better basic fundamentals understanding will have lesser bottleneck in your coding progress.

I was once also new to kotlin and firebase during my final year project in my college days. Back then there wasn't any much solutions as compared to now.

As for your upload files etc functions, maybe this video can be a first stepping stone guide to upload images:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmpD2DqQYVk&ab_channel=Foxandroid

Comment: Thanks @JJSIMCYBERTECH, My project is already linked to firebase and authentication is perfect, I even have a user profile image uploaded and displayed when the user is logged in, Now I need to be able to upload other types of files to firebase and retrieve them when need be. But I am stuck at storing the url of the files in order to retrieve them later on.

Comment: I even tried to do that using java but stuck with this error which says cannot resolve getUploadUrl() with taskSnapshop thing

Comment: So currently you are having issues with reading the files that have been uploaded to the firebase storage? What is your code like?

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //getting the upload
                Upload upload = uploadList.get(i);

                //Opening the upload file in browser using the upload url
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(upload.getUrl()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Comment: public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textViewStatus.setText("File Uploaded Successfully");

                        Upload upload = new Upload(editTextFilename.getText().toString(), taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        mDatabaseReference.child(mDatabaseReference.push().getKey()).setValue(upload);
                    }

Comment: Sorry that this comment section doesn't permit long text so I couldn't give detailed code, the second code is when I am saving the url on firebase database, the first one is when i am trying to read, they say couldn't find the activity to open the intent or something laat